# Differences between AuthenticationProvider and AuthenticationEntryPoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Sorry guys, maybe a silly question.

But I need to implement some additional logic for authentication and authorization in my web app and I've not clear in mind where `AuthenticationProvider` and `AuthenticationEntryPoint` must be used.

Looking for some examples I somethimes find that an `AuthenticationEntryPoint` is omitted in `security:http` section.

But there are situations where also `AuthenticationProvider` is omitted (a default instance is provided by the framework?) and only a `UserDetailsService` implementation is needed.

Please, can you clarify some basic concepts?

Answer (score 14):

Short answer:

1. Implement [`AuthenticationProvider`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html) in order to integrate your custom *authentication* scheme into Spring Security.
2. Implement [`AccessDecisionVoter`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDecisionVoter.html) in order to integrate your custom *authorization* scheme into Spring Security. You *might* also need to implement a custom [`AccessDecisionManager`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDecisionManager.html) in some particular cases, altough the bundled ones are typically enough.

Note that neither of those is web-specific, in contrast with [`AuthenticationEntryPoint`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.html), that is a part of Spring Security *Web* and not Spring Security Core. The main function of `AuthenticationEntryPoint` is to allow the framework to send some sort of "to access this resource you must authenticate first" notification from application server to web client. Most standard notifications are already implemented in Spring Security Web. For example:

- [`BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.html): This is used with Basic authentication. The "notification" is a HTTP 401 response.
- [`LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.html): Your typical "redirect to login page" behaviour.
- [`CasAuthenticationEntryPoint`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.html): Similar to the former, redirects to an enterprise-wide login page to perform SSO via [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service).
- [`Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint.html): The notification is just an HTTP 403 response. This is useful when you use pre-authentication (such as client X.509 certificates) and the user credentials do not provide access.
- ...

As you can see, unless your required behaviour is too specific, you should not need to provide your own implementation of `AuthenticationEntryPoint`.

Comment: Then how `AccessDeniedHandler` differ from `AuthenticationEntryPoint` ?